# Call Python inside C++, how to get tuple output from python?

Tags: python, c++, embed, pyobject

I've got *solver.py* which has *solver: tuple -> tuple* function.

My usage of python in C++ looks like this:

```
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *name, *load_module, *func, *callfunc, *args;
    name = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"solver");
    load_module = PyImport_Import(name);
    func = PyObject_GetAttrString(load_module, (char*)"solver");
    args = PyTuple_Pack(4,
        PyFloat_FromDouble(var1),
        PyFloat_FromDouble(var2),
        PyFloat_FromDouble(var3),
        PyFloat_FromDouble(var4)
    );
    callfunc = PyObject_CallObject(func, args);
    vector<double> solver_out = ???(callfunc);
    Py_Finalize();
```

I have a problem in getting a tuple from *callfunc*, i can't find the appropriate function which would convert the result of PyObject_CallObject to c++ vector. As I said before, python func returns tuple.

I'll be grateful for any help!

I've tried to find smth like "PyObject_AsTuple(callfunc)" but all didn't work.

Comment: There's example code here: https://gist.github.com/zouzias/d367c623faad9483061e6e00028d7b09